# How to create custom arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create an array in the following format:

```
// Required JSON format to create javascript dynamically
[{id:0,[{'val':1,'bool':true},{'val':2,'bool':true}]}]
```

I tried using the javascript `push` method as follows:

```
var arr2 = [];
var arr3 = arr2.push({'id':0,'value':1,'bool':true});
```

But this is not giving the desired format. I don't know how to group by a common `id`. Anyone knows please help me.

Comment: This is because the JSON is invalid

Comment: Your initial structure is invalid

Comment: @Salketer what does JSON have to do with any of this?

Comment: @charlietfl the first part reads "Required Json Format" hence hinting this has to do with json ;)

Comment: @Salketer only in the head of OP

Comment: JSON is  string data format and not relevant to anything shown other than OP has used incorrect terminology

Comment: Please share correct object.

Comment: Yes if the OP had JSON as a tag I would have removed it

Comment: You guys are certainly right. But even if it ain't JSON, it ain't anything valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it isn't a valid object, your array of `{ val:..,'bool': .. }` needs a key. Like so:

```
var ob = { id: 0,
  meaningfulName: [
    {'val':1,'bool':true},
    {'val':2,'bool':true}
  ]};
```

Also having object keys of `'val'` and `'bool'` aren't very meaningful, choose a name that represents what they are.